# Movie with giant robotic spiders that eat people by firing red lasers at them

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm watching a film about an alien invasion, but I don't know the title.

There are alien robots that resemble long-legged spiders, and they eat people by firing a red laser at them. I remember that the protagonist's son was hit by one of the lasers and ended up inside the stomach of one of the spider robots.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This is both brief and (not to be rude) quite hard to understand. I recommend [reading this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for tips on how you could expand this question to be easier to identify.

Comment: Giant spiders with fricking lasers on their heads? Thanks for that image.

Comment: War of the Worlds (2005)? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxnRWFRTX3E

Comment: @Valorum no red lasers, innit?

Comment: You were watching it live? Do you remember the channel it aired on?

Comment: @valorum : the protagonist's son ending in the stomach of one of the robot spider really make me think of War of the world too.

Comment: So, the lasers stunned people allowing the spiders to eat them whole? Or are they some kind of teleporter beam? Was it animated or live action?